# How to display Sub categories of main categories in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How to display Sub categories of main categories in wordpress? like
Categories
     Sub Categories 1
     Sub Categories 2

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) function. Like this:

```
<?php
    $cat = get_categories(array('child_of' => 3));
    var_dump($cat);
?>
```

The child_of parameter is the ID of the parent category. It will return all the sub categories of that parent category.

Sample output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#74 (15) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    &string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    &string(19) "Child 1 of Parent 1"
    ["slug"]=>
    &string(16) "child-1-parent-1"
    ["term_group"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["description"]=>
    &string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    &string(1) "3"
    ["count"]=>
    &string(1) "1"
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    &string(1) "4"
    ["category_count"]=>
    &string(1) "1"
    ["category_description"]=>
    &string(0) ""
    ["cat_name"]=>
    &string(19) "Child 1 of Parent 1"
    ["category_nicename"]=>
    &string(16) "child-1-parent-1"
    ["category_parent"]=>
    &string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#114 (15) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    &string(1) "5"
    ["name"]=>
    &string(19) "Child 2 of Parent 1"
    ["slug"]=>
    &string(16) "child-2-parent-1"
    ["term_group"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["description"]=>
    &string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    &string(1) "3"
    ["count"]=>
    &string(1) "1"
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    &string(1) "5"
    ["category_count"]=>
    &string(1) "1"
    ["category_description"]=>
    &string(0) ""
    ["cat_name"]=>
    &string(19) "Child 2 of Parent 1"
    ["category_nicename"]=>
    &string(16) "child-2-parent-1"
    ["category_parent"]=>
    &string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> First you need to parent category id then you can get its sub category from table wp_term_taxonomy

```
<?php global $wpdb;$prefix=$wpdb->prefix;

$subcateogyr_list=$wpdb->get_results("Select * from ".$prefix."term_taxonomy WHERE parent='parent_category_id'");

foreach($subcateogyr_list as $subcat

   echo  $subcat_name=$wpdb->get_var("select name from ".$prefix."wp_terms where term_taxonomy_id='$subcat['term_id']'");

}
?>
```